# Can an Angular Component mimic a ViewChild from outside?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have written a custom component (let's call it FeatureInput) that is nothing more than a composition of a feature rich component (let's assume for the example an input) and a button. Like this:

```
<div class="niceArrangement">
  <input>
  <button (click)="addSpecialCharacterToInput()">
</div>
```

As the FeatureInput component is overall just an input with a minimal addition, I would like it to behave exactly like an input for the eventual (developing) user - so that it can be given a label, exposes the NgModel of the inner input, has all the Inputs and Outputs etc.

The only option I found would be to manually add every field of the input to FeatureInput, which will be a lot of boilerplate code. Is there any other option?

Comment: I think (control value accessor)[https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor] is what you are looking for.

Comment: You could create some default input class with all the boiler plate and then extend that, which would be easily reusable for similar presentation components in the future.

Comment: Would that be feasible even if it is a third-party component you are wrapping up?